# How do I split a long list in python 3? And print them individually indented?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know how to print things from a list individually and indented. For example:

```
l = ['- cat', '- dog', '- mouse', '- frog', '- hamster']
lsplit = l.split
for i in range(len(l)):
print(lsplit)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I would like to print something like this:

```
- cat
- dog
- mouse
- frog
- hamster
```

I learned how to do it, I just totally forgot...  I've been looking around for an hour or so and haven't found what I was looking for.  I know I have to use `.split()` in a for loop I think...

Comment: A side note: The `s.split` is for splitting a string and returning the list. However, you have to add parentheses (like `s.split()`). Otherwise, it will not be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a `for` loop nor for the use of `split`. I would advise simply using `.join` and `\n` (newline character) to place each element on a separate line, like this:

```
my_list = ['- cat', '- dog', '- mouse', '- frog', '- hamster']
print ("\n".join(my_list))
```

**Outputs:**

```
- cat
- dog
- mouse
- frog
- hamster
```

Note that I used `my_list` as opposed to `l`, as (*as mentioned in the comments*) `l` could easily be mistaken for a `1` and is thus not the best variable name. Furthermore, you should note that your error is a result of `.split()` being a built in method for *strings*. You can find it in the documentation for built-in string operations [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).

Should you really want to use a `for` loop to solve this problem, you could simply iterate over each element in your list and `print` it, as doing so implicitly forms a new line with each iteration.

```
for element in my_list:
    print (element)
```

Comment: @MaxOwnz In this case `join` is indeed the best approach, but I just want to point out the iteration approach as well, since it seems like you may be overusing the `range(len(mylist))` approach. `for line in l: print(line)`.

Comment: I suggest to use a different identifier than `l`. It may be confused with `1` in source code. Such bug can be difficult to find.